# How can I get rid of the GNOME volume overlay?

Tags: unity, gnome

I installed GNOME Shell a while back, but then removed it. However, even while using Unity, I still get GNOME-style volume overlays/notifications.

How can I get back the default Unity-style volume notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, you can run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure notify-osd
```

This appears to, almost never but still occasionally, cause notifications to completely disappear for the session.

Also, this command only works for the current session. The workaround survives suspends and locks but not restarts and logouts.